# Converter doesn't get called

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, converters

I declared converter in xaml:

```
<local:StringToWidthConverter x:Key="Converter" />
```

and

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Monitor 4"
                Width="{Binding Monitor4, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, ConverterParameter=Auto}">
```

Converter class defined as:

```
public class StringToWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (string)value == null ? 0.0 : parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Monitor4 definition is:

```
public string Monitor4
{
    get { return monitor4; }
    set
    {
        monitor4 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Monitor4");
    }
}
```

but the converter never get called? any suggestion would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the converter declared in the XAML file where the GridViewColumn is?

Comment: @IvanVargas I tried to declared in windows resources and listview resources, didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The only cause I can think of is you forget to set the `DataContext` so there is no source to bind at all.

```
this.DataContext = The_View_Model;
```

If the `DataContext` is set properly, how do you know the converter is not executed? Set a breakpoint in the `Convert` method, is breakpoint hit or not?

If you have set the `DataContext` properly and some binding is not working, look at the Output window, there should be some binding error - unlike unhandled exceptions, VS just logs the binding errors silently without terminating the app.

For example, if you bind to a property `Monitor4` which turns out to be nonexistent:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Monitor4' property not found on 'object' ''ConverterWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Monitor4; DataItem='ConverterWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

If the value converter is not working correctly

> System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'Auto' (type 'String')

In your case, you cannot convert a string value `Auto` to a `Double`. You can return `System.Double.NaN` instead.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (string)value == null ? 0.0 : System.Double.NaN; 
}
```

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the issue and the only reason it didn't work was because of DataContext

Comment: @briswill have you found the cause?

Comment: @phuzi Thank you for the help. I have found the issue. I have a class named "ProfileItem" which include the property "Monitor4". In the ViewModel, there is a list of this class is binding to a listview. Each property in the class is binding to a column in the listview. On GridViewColumn level, it seems like it can only bind to a property in the ViewModel which I defined later as "columnwidth" in the ViewModel class. It was successfully binded with the GridViewColumn, and converter was able to work properly. I still don't understand why GridViewColumn can't bind with a property from other class

Comment: I have derived INotifyPropertyChanged for "ProfileItem" too. it still cannot bind the GridViewColumn. Any ideas?

Comment: @briswill the difference is a single object (the ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged) vs. a list of objects (the list inside the ViewModel which is an ObsevableColllection<T>). In the listview, there are many rows, but there is only one header, all rows share the same header column definitions, that is why the header column width can only bind to the single object - the ViewModel itself.

Comment: If the Monitor4 property is defined in the ProfileItem class, and you bind to the ObservableCollection<ProfileItem> list, then there are different values for Monitor4 so how is the column width supposed to be calculated?